Asymptotic states and physical states in QFT scattering theory
Context
In the scattering theory of QFT, one may impose the asymptotic conditions on the field:
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\pm\infty} \langle \alpha | \hat{\phi}(t,\mathbf{x}) | \beta \rangle = \sqrt{Z} \langle \alpha | \hat{\phi}_{\text{in,out}}(t,\mathbf{x}) | \beta \rangle.
\end{align}
Further, the asymptotic fields $\hat{\phi}_{\text{in,out}}(t,\mathbf{x})$ satisfies the equations without interaction, e.g. for $\phi^4$ theory
$$(\Box + m^2)\hat{\phi}(t,\mathbf{x})  + \frac{\lambda}{3!}\hat{\phi}^3(t,\mathbf{x}) = 0 \quad \quad(\Box + m^2)\hat{\phi}_{\text{in,out}}(t,\mathbf{x}) = 0.$$
They, thus, justify that we can apply the mode expansions:
$$\hat{\phi}_{\text{in,out}}(x) = \int d^3 \mathbf{k} \; \hat{a}(\mathbf{k})_{\text{in,out}}e^{-ik\cdot x} + h.c. $$
As a result, they build the Fock space as:
$$\mathcal{H}_{\text{in,out}} = \text{span}\bigg\{\prod_{i=0}^N \hat{a}^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k}_i)_{\text{in,out}} |\Omega \rangle  \bigg| N \in \mathbb{Z} \bigg\} $$
where $|\Omega\rangle$ is the vacuum state. Specially, the asymptotic $1$-particle state is:
$$| \mathbf{k}; \text{in,out} \rangle = a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k})_{\text{in,out}} | \Omega \rangle. $$
Questions

They are using Heisenberg picture w.r.t. some reference time $t_0$. From the elementary Quantum mechanics knowledge, the state in Schrodinger picture at $t_0$ is the corresponding state in Heisenberg picture, i.e. $|\psi_{S}(t_0)\rangle = |\psi_{H}\rangle$. Thus, I think I can write:
$$|\mathbf{k};\text{in}\rangle = |\psi_{\mathbf{k},in}(t_0)\rangle \quad\quad |\mathbf{k};\text{out}\rangle = |\psi_{\mathbf{k},out}(t_0)\rangle$$
where $|\psi_{\mathbf{k},in/out}(t_0)\rangle$ are the corresponding states in Schrodinger picture. Is this statement correct?

Moreover, since a field theory with Poincare symmetry possesses Poincare algebra: $[P^{\mu},P^{\nu}] = 0 、 \cdots$, we can define the simultaneous eigenstate:
$$H |\lambda_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle = E_{\mathbf{k}}(\lambda)|\lambda_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle  \quad \quad \mathbf{P}|\lambda_{\mathbf{k}} \rangle  = \mathbf{k}|\lambda(\mathbf{k})\rangle $$
One can define $1$-particle state $|1_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle $ as the eigenstate of $$(H,\mathbf{P}) \quad \text{with eigenvalues} \quad (\sqrt{\mathbf{k}^2 + m^2},\mathbf{k}).$$
What is the relation between $|\mathbf{k};\text{in,out}\rangle$ and $|1_{\mathbf{k}}\rangle $?

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the physical Hilbert space, i.e. the space field operator $\hat{\phi}$ acts on. What is the relation between $\mathcal{H}_{\text{in,out}}$ and the $\mathcal{H}$? I think they are isomorphic, i.e. $\mathcal{H}_{\text{in,out}}\sim \mathcal{H}$. If so, how can I write a bound state, such as positronium $|e^+e^-\rangle$ in QED, in term of the state in $\mathcal{H}_{\text{in,out}}$?


